# pushReplacementNamed doesn't work correctly on Drawer

Tags: android, visual-studio, flutter, routes, drawer

I'm a beginner on flutter and I'm making an APP but I have this problem :

In the main, I write this code :

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: ImgProvider(),
        ), // create the provider of images
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Saved(),
        ), // create the provider of Saved
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'HTrip',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.green,
          accentColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
        ),
        home: SelectionPages(),
        routes: {
          '/saved'  :   (context) => SavedScreen(),
        }, // define the main page to be displayed
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and In the SelectionPages()  , I wrote this :

```
drawer: Account(),
```

and In the Account() , I wrote this :

```
class Account extends StatelessWidget {
  Account();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final savedItem = Provider.of<Saved>(context);
    return Drawer(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              AppBar(
          title: Text("Account"),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        Divider(),
        ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.sd_card),
                title: Text("Saved"),
                onTap: () {
                  debugPrint("Hello button is clicked");
                  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/saved');
                  },
                // dense: true,
                trailing: Chip(
                  label: Text('${savedItem.savedCount}'),
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                ),
                //  enabled: true,
              )
            ]
          )
    );
  }
}
```

and In SavedScreen(), I wrote this:

```
class SavedScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  //static const routeName = '/Saved';

  @override
  _SavedScreenState createState() => _SavedScreenState();
}

class _SavedScreenState extends State<SavedScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final savedItem = Provider.of<Saved>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Saved")),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Card(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Saved item',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                    Spacer(), // to take all the empty space available in this place
                    Chip(
                      label: Text('${savedItem.savedCount}'),
                    ),
                    FlatButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("See all")),
                  ]),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Card(
              child: ImgSavedGridView(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But when I run the App and I click on "Saved" ( where I run this "Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/saved');") I got this error :

```
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (27612): Hello button is clicked

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/saved", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

PS : when I changed "Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/saved');" to "Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/');". it go to home page with no problem

please Help me!

I'm here for any clarification.

Thanks

Comment: it is working completely fine. however you are not using provider correctly.

Comment: can you please , explain to me how can I use provider correctly so can my program work?

Comment: Actually issue is not because of provider, that’s why i didn’t answer yet. can you try flutter clean also add SavedScreen widget. can you also try removing all providers ?

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "flutter clean" ?

Comment: stop your app and run flutter clean command in terminal and again run app check the app then.

Comment: I stoppe the app and I ran " flutter clean" on Terminal then when It's finished I start the app again.
but I got same problem.

Comment: did you try after removing all providers ? i am not even able to run code because of wrong use of provider. your code is running or are you getting errors ?@ismail

Comment: No, Do you mean all the providers from all the App ?
I think I can't do that because the entire app work with providers!!

Comment: can you make sure that, you did not added MaterialApp widget in SelectionPages  class ?

Comment: I think you will get errors because you don't have all the function.
no have no problem when I run the app just when I click on saved.

Comment: I did , I add MaterialApp on SelectionPages !

Comment: that's why you are getting error, just remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from our discussion, you are using MaterialApp widget in SelectionPages also where you didn't define routing, but navigator look for routing over their.

Just remove MaterialApp widget in SelectionPages will solve your issue.